# Simulate a cell/row click on the selected row of a dbgrid. Delphi

Tags: delphi, dbgrid, tdbgrid

I have a dbgrid on my form which contains code to show user information and a user image in a panel when the users row is clicked (oncellclick procedure). The code uses the id of the row clicked to display data for editing and display the image of the user (saved with the user's id in a folder).

I also have a search button which selects a user who's id is the same as the id searched. This functions correctly, as the user's row is the only one shown and is selected after the search.

However, the user information is not shown in the panel, as the selected row has not been clicked. Is there a way to simulate a cell click for the selected row so that the user information can be displayed, after the search is complete?

I have tried to use `Grid.Perform(WM_LBUTTONDOWN,0,0)` with no success.

Comment: Make a method which updates that info and call that method instead. You'll call the same method when you select a row as well.

Comment: I thin ki;ve been coding for too long. I should've seen that... Thanks @TLama